# Python <-> C++ object oriented communication

Tags: c++, python, boost, ipc, rpc

I want to write a daemon in C++, which will hold a graph data structure and will compute some dependencies. I also want to have Python Batch (also a daemon - a backend to HTML based GUI), which will allow users to interactivly operate on these C++ structures - add / remove / connect / ... nodes and read results of computations.

I would love to choose the best communication mechanism available.

The mandatory functionality is:

1. Python and C++ should be able to operate on nodes in object oriented way, so I would love to be able to write code like `n1 = node('a'); n2 = n1.add_subnode('b'); n2.ports('test').connect(node('c'))`
2. The Python Batch does NOT have to be "separated" from the C++ daemon - they can have the same lifetime (but it would be good to somehow separate batch from C++ daemon in case of C++ crash or something wrong - this separation is optional)
3. The communication should be fast - the Python should be able to get information about a lot of nodes and allow end - users to work smoothly as much as possible.

Currently I was thinking about:

1. IPC (like [0MQ](http://www.zeromq.org/)) with some kind of data serialization mechanism.
2. RPC based on [Protocol Buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) or [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/).
3. Integration based on [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/index.html)

The IPC and RPC solutions seems good, but I have to write a big wrappers to get the functionality from point 1. On the other hand I have found no information about using Boost.Python in C++ daemon and I don't know if it is even possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Boost.Python may be used in a daemon.
2. Thrift and Protocol Buffers work fine. Thrift implements a full RPC server while protobuf, unless the situation has changed last year, just offers serialization. Personally I would prefer Thrift.

The differences between these two solutions are speed (Boost.Python is definitely faster, though RPC is not really slow if you specify correct socket options -- TCP_NODELAY etc.) and the fact that in case of Boost.Python your binary depends on a certain version of Python. In case of Thrift you have less dependencies, especially if the Thrift itself is installed as a package for your OS distribution. Anyway, this is a question of performance and deployment. It cannot be answered without knowing how fast the communication should be, and also where and how you are going to deploy your program.

UPD: Do you really need to write your daemon in C++? If that is because of heavy computation performed on graph, maybe only the computational part should be in C++ (an extension module)? Extending is usually preferred to other techniques.

Comment: Thank you, the C++ daemon has to be written in C++ but after some investigation I came across an idea, it does not have to be daemon - it could be written as set of libraries used by Python using `Cython` / `Boost.Python`. The C++ part is a compiler under the hood, which compiles the graph to some binary machine code. I think I found the solution - making Python the daemon which would call some functions from my C++ libs using `Cython` is very good solution.

Comment: Agree. Generally it is the best possible option: to implement general control logic in Python and provide things that can not be done in Python as extension modules implemented in C++.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Cython. It has very decent [C++ integration](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html). It gives you a lot of freedom to use C++ with rather little effort, i.e. nearly no boilerplate. C++ exception become Python exceptions. Still, you can fine tune a lot of things. You should try it out.